# "Missing required entitlement" for NFCTagReaderSession

Tags: swift, nfc, core-nfc, ios13

I'm diving into iOS 13's new CoreNFC capabilities, and I'm struggling to get NFCTagReaderSession working.  After setting up my entitlements and instantiating an NFCTagReaderSession and delegate I attempt to start the session by calling `nfcTagReaderSession?.begin()`.  My session immediately gets invalidated with this error:

`Error Domain=NFCError Code=2 "Missing required entitlement" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing required entitlement}`

I followed the documentation here for my entitlements file: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_nfc_readersession_formats

I have also added the appropriate "Privacy - NFC Scan Usage Description" in my Info.plist.

Has anyone gotten this to work yet?  Is this just a problem with Xcode 11 or iOS 13?

Here is the code in my ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreNFC

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var nfcTagReaderSession: NFCTagReaderSession?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        nfcTagReaderSession = NFCTagReaderSession(pollingOption: [.iso14443, .iso15693, .iso18092], delegate: self)
        nfcTagReaderSession?.begin()
        print("isReady: \(nfcTagReaderSession?.isReady)")
    }
}

extension ViewController: NFCTagReaderSessionDelegate {
    func tagReaderSessionDidBecomeActive(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession) {
        print("Tag reader did become active")
    }

    func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
        print("\(error)")
    }

    func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {
        print("\(tags)")
    }
}
```

Here is my entitlements file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats</key>
    <array>
        <string>TAG</string>
        <string>NDEF</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Almost the same as you are on nfciso15693tag. see:<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000388/missing-required-entitlement-for-nfciso15693tag-customcommand>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem, but it is gone after removing and adding **Near Field Communication Tag Reading** in Capabilities.

My entitlements file have a little differ:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:example.com</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats</key>
    <array>
        <string>NDEF</string>
        <string>TAG</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

But I don't think this is it.

Also, you can try to modify Apple example to fit your needs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/building_an_nfc_tag-reader_app

Or just remove **.iso18092** from polling options and it will work. I think this standard require specific entitlement.

Comment: I removed . iso18092 but doesn't read iso14443 tags. Any suggestion?

Comment: Removing .iso18092 worked! Thanks so much, Stanislav!  I'm able to read standard iso14443 tags.  I cannot, however, read the Mifare Classic variant of the iso14443 tags.  Any idea if Apple is excluding the Mifare Classic on purpose?

Comment: @Byteros, no, I completely forgot that my passport has NFC tag. Try to do it later.

Comment: @StevenBerard, I can not read the Mifare too. Still, don`t know how to make it work. Hope the Friday session clear something and they did not exclude this specification.

Comment: @StevenBerard I can read Mifare tags, without remove iso18092 from polling list but I cannot read the passport. I Don't know why...

Comment: @Byteros I can't read ePassports too, it looks like it isn't even detecting the NFC chip of it

Comment: @Byteros I found the solution for the ePassport. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56516232/2652054

Comment: @StevenBerard I can not read Mifare too with an iPhone 7. I try with an ePassport and its ok but no Mifare tags.

Comment: Is it possible to increase the timeout of NFCTagReaderSession? By default it is set to 20 seconds

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58191748/nfctagreadersession-has-timeout-of-20-seconds-how-to-increase-it

Answer (score 12):

[image: info.plist]add this keys to **info.plist** like this

```
<key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers</key>
<array>
    <string>D2760000850101</string>
</array>
<key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.felica.systemcodes</key>
<array>
    <string>12FC</string>
</array>
```

Comment: How do you fix the resulting "Provisioning profile "JAN DEV" doesn't include the com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.felica.systemcodes and com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers entitlements." error?

Comment: @JanMoritz try "ISO7816 application identifiers for NFC Tag Reader Session"  "D2760000850101" and "ISO18092 system codes for NFC Tag Reader Session"  "12FC"

Comment: I put it in the entitlements. My fault.

Comment: I also put it in the entitlements and got same error. Thanks for your fault.

Comment: I followed each step but I'm not able to run application in release mode. Am i missing something ? @muyoungko

Answer (score 6):

To read ePassports, besides adding the **Near Field Communication Tag Reading** in Capabilities, you will need to add the following AID key and value in info.plist:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers</key>
<array>
    <string>A0000002471001</string>
</array>
```

Comment: @JanMoritz We are two 

Comment: I found that this worked in combination with <string>00000000000000</string> ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56516232/1277350

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this keys to info.plist:

ISO7816 application identifiers for NFC Tag Reader Session

ISO18092 system codes for NFC Tag Reader Session

I don't know the value for this. I did an example of a project but I can't read anything from my ePassport. On Friday there will be an event where I hope that everything will become clear: [link](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/715)

Comment: Ya. I'm waiting with bated breath for the Friday session.  I really wish I decided to go to San Jose this year to talk to the engineers.  For now, I'm just removing the option to read ISO 18092 tags.

Comment: Why can't you read from the ePassport? Isn't it detecting the Tag?

Comment: @JanMoritz yes, tagReaderSession(didDetect:) callback is no fired with ePassport or eID. I've more lucky with Mifare tags.

Comment: @Byteros same for me using german ePassport/eID. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Byteros https://twitter.com/maartenwegdam/status/1136220776485535746 apparently they were able to make it work. Perhaps we are doing something wrong.

Comment: @JanMoritz yes maybe.

Comment: The video is out and he keeps talking about reading the NFC chip of the passport in it. But still doesn't work for me.