# Example on how to use NFCTagReaderSession

Tags: swift, nfc, ios13

I was not able to find a working example using the new NFCTagReaderSession functionality that has been introduced in iOS 13.
Perhaps some one could post one here.

Answer (score 1):

please have a look at this stackoverflow entry - 
it already contains some more infos:
["Missing required entitlement" for NFCTagReaderSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56453525/missing-required-entitlement-for-nfctagreadersession)

e.g. after adding the entitlement, and the plist entry, you should focus on a supported polling option like iso 14443

Comment: Kindly try to add a brief explanation of what's in the link to your answer. it will give it more value.

Comment: sure - the link shows some code snippets for implementation, however it won't work if include . iso18092 right now - which might be possible soon - so you should focus on one of the other options