# Trouble reading eID information with NFC using iOS13

Tags: ios, swift, nfc, ios13

Coming from a similar question ( [Cannot read the NFC chip of the ePassport using iOS13](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56515747) ) I am also trying to read the information on the eID using iOS13 following the same approach as the other question, but I can't seem to get the steps after scanning the document to work. ( like using the MRZ code to create a BAC and reading the data accordingly )

Any advice or more information? Did someone managed to get this working already? Thanks a lot!

**Edit**: Added current working code to improve and clarify the question.

```swift
import UIKit
import CoreNFC

class ViewController: UIViewController, NFCTagReaderSessionDelegate {

    var readerSession: NFCTagReaderSession?

    func tagReaderSessionDidBecomeActive(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession) {

    }

    func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }

    func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {
        var ndefTag: NFCNDEFTag

        switch tags.first! {
            case let .iso7816(tag):
                ndefTag = tag
            default:
                session.invalidate(errorMessage: "Card not valid")
                return
        }

        session.connect(to: tags.first!) { (error: Error?) in
            if error != nil {
                session.invalidate(errorMessage: "Connection error. Please try again.")
                return
            }

            let card: NFCISO7816Tag
            card = ndefTag as! NFCISO7816Tag

            print(card)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func nfcButton(_ sender: Any) {
        guard NFCNDEFReaderSession.readingAvailable else {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(
                title: "Scanning Not Supported",
                message: "This device doesn't support scanning your identity document.",
                preferredStyle: .alert
            )

            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }

        readerSession = NFCTagReaderSession(pollingOption: [.iso14443], delegate: self, queue: nil)
        readerSession?.alertMessage = "Place the device on the identity document."
        readerSession?.begin()
    }
}
```

Comment: What eID are you talking about? The dutch one? In the question title you are saying you have trouble reading the ePassport and in the description you are talking about the eID, this is confusing.

Comment: I am talking about the Dutch eID, I changed the title to prevent further confusion, thanks!

Comment: Is ```tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag])``` being called?

Comment: I have added my code to clarify my question and show my progress so far. `tagReaderSession` is being called and I parsed the result into a NFCISO7816Tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag])` implementation looks wrong to me. You are converting an NFCISO7816Tag to an NFCNDEFTag then back to an NFCISO7816Tag.
The implementation should look like this:

```
func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {

    let tag = tags.first!

    nfcTagReaderSession?.connect(to: tag) { (error: Error?) in
            if case let .iso7816(iso7816Tag) = tag {
                // do your magic with iso7816Tag here
             }
     }
}
```

Reading the content of the ePassport/eID NFC chip isn't as straigforward as reading a simple NDEF tag.
The working example provided in [Appendix D to Part 11](https://www.icao.int/publications/Documents/9303_p11_cons_en.pdf) of the Doc9303 from the ICAO is of great help to understand what needs to be implemented.

For my part I am almost done implementing it in swift and will publish the source code under the MIT license once my app is on the app store.
To do so I included some C/C++ code that was taken from here: https://github.com/UBIC-repo/core/tree/master/PassportReader/Reader

You will probably need to use some bridging to C in order to do the 3DES encryption/decryption and checksum calculations.

EDIT: Someone already posted a working source code here: https://github.com/AndyQ/NFCPassportReader