# "Missing required entitlement" for NFCISO15693Tag customCommand

Tags: swift, ios13, iso-15693, core-nfc

In iOS13 beta version. when I tried use the NFCISO15693Tag api 
`customCommandWithRequestFlag:customCommandCode:customRequestParameters:completionHandler:` 
send customCommand code to the tag , 
I got the error:

```
-[NFCTagReaderSession transceive:tagUpdate:error:]:706  Error Domain=NFCError Code=2 "Missing required entitlement" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing required entitlement}
```

I have tried:

1, Reconfig the Privacy of NFC.

2, Add the config in my info.plist

```
<key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.felica.systemcodes</key>
    <array>
        <string>12FC</string>
    </array>
<key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>D2760000850101</string>
    </array>
```

But , none of them work for me .

The following is my source code:

```swift
func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {
    if let st = tags.first {

    session.connect(to: st) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            session.invalidate(errorMessage: "Connection error. Please try again.")
            return
        }
        if case let .iso15693(type5Tag) = st {

            print(type5Tag.identifier.toString())
            print(type5Tag.icSerialNumber.toString())
            print(type5Tag.isAvailable)

            type5Tag.select(requestFlags: [.address, .highDataRate]) { (selectError) in
                print("selectError")
                print(selectError)
            }

            type5Tag.customCommand(requestFlags: [.highDataRate, .address], customCommandCode: 0xB4, customRequestParameters: Data([0x02])) { (data, error) in
                print("custom command: get random number")
                print(data.toString())
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Actually, I get the following error:

```
-[NFCTagReaderSession transceive:tagUpdate:error:]:706  Error Domain=NFCError Code=2 "Missing required entitlement" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing required entitlement}
```

expect 4 bytes random number.

Comment: Got the answer. not support in iOS13 beta3 yet.
<https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117860>

Comment: Support was added in Beta 4, but I'm able to reproduce the bug on iOS 13.1 production